# How to Moq a Method that Have parameters and have to do something with a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq

I have set a test using Moq 3.0. I need to test a method that will change some value in that database. I am using ASP.NET MVC so I want to test my controller.

I setup this

```
 // Generate an implementer of IProductsRepository at runtime using Moq
 var mockTareasRepos = new Mock<IRepository>();
 mockTareasRepos.Setup(x => x.ExecutedTask).Returns(tasks.AsQueryable());
 return mockTareasRepos.Object;
```

I need to add a new method that get a taskId and change the value of a field in a list of tasks. Suppose that the value I need to change is StartTime that is a datetime, I need to set the value to null and I need to set that retrys value plus one.

this is the task Class

```
public class {
     int taskId {get;set;}
     DateTime StartTime  {get;set;}
     int retrys {get;set;}
}
```

How I do that?

```
 mockTareasRepos.Setup(x => x.SetToExecuteTask(It.IsAny<int>()))
```

I hope you understand what I need, My English is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correcly, you want to test that after calling your Controller's method, your database value should be updated. Your mocking your repository because you don't want to setup a test database, right? So, your test should be something like this:

```
mockTareasRepos.Setup(...) //Do the setup you need.
var controller = new YourController(mockTareasRepos);
controller.YourMethod();
mockTareasRepos.Verify(x => x.YourRepositoryUpdateMethod(It.IsAny<Task>, Times.Once()));
```

The last line will verify if your controller called the 'YourRepositoryUpdateMethod' method once. By doing this, your testing that your controller method calls the Repository interface to update your database.

I hope it helps. If this is not what your looking for, please, give us more information.

Comment: It helps but I still need to execute some king of method so I can have for example a object remove form the list - like if its remove form the database - because my controller should give me the value of   Coutn of the list.

Comment: What is the responsability of your CONTROLLER? Test that, not your repository, that's why your mocking it. You don't need to test if your repository is removing something from a list because that is the resposability of the repository, not the Controller's (which is the System Under Test).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `Callback` method:

```
mockTareasRepos.Setup(x => x.RepositoryMethod(...))
    .Callback<IEnumerable<Task>>(tasks => /* modify tasks here */);
    .Returns(tasks.AsQueryable());
```